# MS Access check next related record to have an indicator popup in form?

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

I have a MS Access form connected to a MySQL database. This form has demographic and lab data. The lab data is on the many-side a 1:n relationship.

Here is the sample lab data:

`Lab_tbl`

`ID (pk)`    `Animal_ID (fk)`    `Fruit`   .......  `Date`

`100`................       `1`..................          `Banana`  .....  `1/1/13`

`101`................          `1`..................              `Apple`  .......  `2/6/12`

`102`................          `2` .................             `Banana` .....   `2/4/13`

`103`  ...............        `1`          .................    `Apple` .......    `1/13/14`

`104`  ...............        `3`    .................          `Pineapple` `3/1/12`

`105` ...............        `2`            .................  `Banana`  .....  `8/16/10`

I want the form to tell the user that an animal has changed the type of food it ate in the table. I have some knowledge in vba, mostly in display, so altering the form is not the issue. The first few steps I've done is running `GROUP BY` Animal_ID and sorting by Fruit ASC. I can't rely on asking the database to check on ID + 1 because the order of adding records will not be sequential to its Animal_ID. I think I need to first `SELECT * FROM Lab_Tbl ORDER BY Fruit ASC, Animal_ID ASC`.  I need help to indicate that the animal ate a different type of fruit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2bc5f/12/0) demonstrates the following query which should give you the newest fruit eaten and the previous fruit eaten for a specific `Animal_ID`:

```
SELECT mt.Animal_ID, mt.id, Fruit AS NewestFruitEaten,
  (
    SELECT st.Fruit
    FROM Lab_tbl AS st
    WHERE st.ID < mt.ID AND st.Animal_ID = 1
    ORDER BY st.ID DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) AS OldFruitEaten
FROM Lab_tbl AS mt
WHERE mt.Animal_ID = 1
ORDER BY mt.ID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you want a complete list of all of the `Animal_ID`s with the newest fruit eaten and previous fruit eaten then the following should work ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2bc5f/28/0)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT did.Animal_ID,
(
  SELECT mt.Fruit
  FROM Lab_tbl AS mt
  WHERE mt.Animal_ID = did.Animal_ID
  ORDER BY mt.ID DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS NewestFruitEaten,
(
  SELECT st.Fruit
  FROM Lab_tbl AS st
  WHERE st.ID < 
  (
    SELECT sst.ID 
    FROM Lab_tbl AS sst
    WHERE sst.Animal_ID = did.Animal_ID
    ORDER BY sst.ID DESC
    LIMIT 1
  )
  AND st.Animal_ID = did.Animal_ID
  ORDER BY st.ID DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS OlderFruitEaten
FROM Lab_tbl AS did
```

***EDIT***, to get a list of animals that ate more than one fruit use the following query ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/423d1/1/0)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Animal_ID 
FROM Lab_tbl t1
INNER JOIN Lab_tbl t2 ON t1.Animal_ID = t2.Animal_ID
  AND t1.Fruit <> t2.Fruit
```

Comment: Yeah, your first query just tells me about 2 values per animal, where in the table Animal 1 has 3 values. Will check the 2nd one.

Comment: The last record entered is the most current fruit an animal ate, correct?  The above queries get that fruit and then compare that to the second to last thing the animal ate.  Are you wanting to know if any particular animal has eaten more than one fruit?

Comment: Yes, that and a list of all animals that have eaten more than one type of fruit. I don't necessarily need to figure out the fruit each animal ate, just whether it ate a different fruit or not.

Comment: **@user3293827**, I edited my answer to provide you with a query that will show all animals that ate more than one type of fruit.  Is that what you are after?